# No module named psycopg2 on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I've installed psycopg2 and even had a pyramid site successfully connect to a database using the driver, but now I can't get it working with an SQLAlchemy scaffold.

Why is there an import error?

I've added this to `development.ini`

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/test
```

**Attempt to start server:**

```
../bin/pserve development.ini --reload
```

**Error:**

```
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 357, in engine_from_config
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 335, in create_engine
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 73, in create
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 371, in dbapi
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

Do I need to install it to the python virtual environment I created for this new site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
bin/easy_install psycopg2
```

Comment: from the virtual env you created?